# Returning a value from a function after processing

Tags: clojure

How do i return a value from a function after doing some processing in clojure.

Code in Java

```
private int add() { 

int i = 0;

if (i == 0) i++; 
if (i == 1) i += 2;
else i += 3;

}
```

I have thought of using let but there are too many if statements hence i am unsure how do i return.

Comment: You don't need 3 ifs for that. You can just do: `i += (i <= 1) ? i+1 : 3;`

Comment: @Nile I am talking about this code in clojue

Comment: @Nile that doesn't look right to me. Should be more like `i += (i <= 1) ? 3-i : 3;` (both of these ignore the possibility of negative numbers, of course).

Comment: You might consider reading through a Clojure tutorial several times, e.g. java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html, then immersing yourself in the Clojure way of thinking, e.g. by doing problems at @amalloy's 4clojure, before trying to translate imperative code. `((comp #(if (= 1 %) (+ 2 %) (+ 3 %)) #(if (zero? %) (inc %) %)) 0)`

Comment: Actually, it occurs to me, the java code can be simplified further: `i += (i == 1) ? 2 : 3`.

Comment: @amalloy Your solutions add 3 when `i = 0`.

Comment: This is a good question that might be expanded a little. I am confused. Are you trying to translate your Java example into Clojure? Does the Java function implicitly return the value, or do you need a return? (Sorry, I don't write Java code.)

Comment: @Nile so does his question code. First he sees that it's 0 and adds one; then he sees that it's 1 and adds two.

Comment: @amalloy: There's no call to `add()` at the end of the function. It's not like that's immediately invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest transliteration is to merely name new locals for each new value of `i`, like so:

```
(defn add []
  (let [i 0
        i' (if (= i 0) (inc i) i)
        i'' (if (= i' 1)
              (+ 2 i')
              (+ 3 i'))]
    i''))
```

All of these locals could have been named `i`, rather than calling them `i'`, but I didn't want to confuse the issue of immutability: we are not modifying `i` in any way, just introducing a new named local bound to a new value.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern of your code is:

```
if-else-expr(init-value) -> value1
if-else-expr(value1) -> value2
if-else-expr(value2) -> value3
if-else-expr...
```

It can be implemented in clojure as

```
(defn add []
  (-> init-value
      (#(if (expr1-1) (expr1-2) (expr1-3)))
      (#(if (expr2-1) (expr2-2) (expr2-3)))
      (#(if (expr3-1) (expr3-2) (expr3-3)))
      ...))
```

In your case:

```
(defn add []
  (-> 0
      (#(if (= % 0) (+ % 1) %))
      (#(if (= % 1) (+ % 2) (+ % 3)))))
```

Comment: Both of these do something different from the posted java, which relied on the zero case being applied *and then* testing for one. ie, if the input is zero, then it gets incremented, then it gets checked to see if it's one. If you try to put this all into a single check you don't carry over the actual meaning of the code.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks. You're absolutely right. I've changed the answer.